# Python: inserting double or single quotes around a string

Tags: python, sql, quotes

Im using python to access a MySQL database and im getting a unknown column in field due to quotes not being around the variable.

code below:

```
cur = x.cnx.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into tempPDBcode (PDBcode) values (%s);' % (s)) 
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

How do i manually insert double or single quotes around the value of s?
I've trying using `str()` and manually concatenating quotes around `s` but it still doesn't work. 
The sql statement works fine iv double and triple check my sql query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use Python's string functions to build the SQL statement. You run the risk of leaving an SQL injection vulnerability. You should do this instead:

```
cur.execute('insert into tempPDBcode (PDBcode) values (%s);', s)
```

Note the comma.

Answer (score 5):

Python will do this for you automatically, if you use the database API:

```
cur = x.cnx.cursor()
cur.execute('insert into tempPDBcode (PDBcode) values (%s)',s)
```

Using the DB API means that python will figure out whether to use quotes or not, and also means that you don't have to worry about SQL-injection attacks, in case your `s` variable happens to contain, say,

```
value'); drop database; '
```

Answer (score -5):

If this were purely a string-handling question, the answer would be tojust put them in the string:

```
cur.execute('insert into tempPDBcode (PDBcode) values ("%s");' % (s))
```

That's the classic use case for why Python supports both kinds of quotes.

However as other answers & comments have pointed out, there are SQL-specific concerns that are relevant in this case.

Comment: Although SQL specifies single quotes around strings, so the single and double quotes there should be swapped

Comment: @Ian - thanks, did not know that about SQL. Clearly I did not understand correctly! I've edited accordingly.

Comment: if you care about SO badges, I believe that by deleting this answer at -3 you'll eventually get the "Peer pressure" badge.